# How to Deploy Angular Website in AWS Cloud9

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-cloud9

I am trying to deploy an Angular Website in AWS Cloud9 but I don't understand the error I'm getting. From what I know, I had to add domain name in ***environmentfolder/cdk/lib/cdk-stack.ts*** file. I have done that and I have also added my AWS account number and region that I'm deploying in ***environmentfolder/cdk/bin/cdk.ts*** file. My command is **npm run deploy**

This is environmentfolder/cdk/bin/cdk.ts file:

```js
    import 'source-map-support/register';
    import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
    import { CdkStack } from '../lib/cdk-stack';
    const app = new cdk.App();
    new CdkStack(app, 'S3AngularWebsite');
    const envUSA = { account: '01234556789', region: 'us-east-2' };
```

And this is my environmentfolder/cdk/lib/cdk-stack.ts file:

```js
    import cdk = require('@aws-cdk/core');
    import s3deploy= require('@aws-cdk/aws-s3-deployment');
    import s3 = require('@aws-cdk/aws-s3');
    import { SPADeploy } from 'cdk-spa-deploy';
    export class CdkStack extends cdk.Stack {
        constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
            super(scope, id, props);
    new SPADeploy(this, 'spaDeploy', { encryptBucket: true })
    .createSiteFromHostedZone({
    zoneName: 'mywebsite.com',
    indexDoc: 'index.html',
    websiteFolder: '../website/dist/website'
    });
    }
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image: This is the error I'm getting]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a folder named "website"? I think you need to double check this value

```js
    websiteFolder: '../website/dist/website'
```

Comment: yes I have a website folder. But not sure what to do next.